# How to fix git add changing folder path capitalization?

Tags: windows, git

My question is about why folder name capitalization is changing from ServerCom to ServerCOM when I stage my changes for this folder? Does git have a configuration to do this?

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
    ServerCom/text.txt
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git add ServerCom/text.txt

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

```
    new file:   ServerCOM/text.txt
```

Comment: I wonder if there is already a file committed with a `ServerCOM` folder name and git thinks they are the same.